# Translate VHDL to Verilog

Tags: translation, vhdl, verilog

I have a problem with translating VHDL to Verilog.
It's part of my source code on VHDL.
With I/O I somehow understood, but have some problems to translate this string

```
ib1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,ib1'length));
```

to verilog?

```
COMPONENT GenerateModel
PORT(
     ib1 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    );
END COMPONENT;
--Inputs
signal ib1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
 BEGIN
uut: GenerateModel PORT MAP (
      ib1 => ib1,
    );
process
begin
    for i in 0 to 15 loop
        ib1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,ib1'length));
        wait for 10 ns;
    end loop;
end process;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not so firm with Verilog, so I'll write a comment: This line is used in a for-loop to iterate from 0 to 15. i is of type INTEGER, but the unit under test (uut) requires a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (slv) to be passed to the component. Your requested line performs a type conversion from INTEGER to slv with UNSIGNED as an intermediate type. to_unsigned converts the INTEGER i to a signal of type UNSIGNED with length of ib1. Afterwards this UNSIGNED is converted to slv. ib1'length accesses the attribute length of vector ib1. Alternatively one could write `to_unsigned(i, 4)`, but length is more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend into Verilog from Paebbels' comment, the line you are looking at does an explicit conversion from the type of the loop variable `i` to the port variable `ib1`. In Verilog, that explicit conversion is not needed, you can just assign the port variable directly. So, for example (in Verilog IEEE 1364-1995 compatible):

```
integer i;

...

for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
  ib1 = i; // <-- The line
  #10; // -- Assume 1 step is 1 ns, can specific timescale if needed
end
```

If you want, you can even loop through the variable directly if its of type `reg` (ie, not a net):

```
for (ib1 = 0; ib1 < 15; ib1 = ib1 + 1) begin
  #10;
end
#10;
```

[Note that as Greg mentioned, you need to be sure you dont create an infinite loop as if `ib1` is 4-bits wide, it will always be less than 16, thus I fixed the example above to loop until `ib1` is 15 (4'b1111)]

Comment: FYI: `ib1 < 16` is an infinite loop because it is 4-bits wide (`4'd15 + 1 == 4'd0`)

Comment: @Greg Yeah, I forgot to mention that you need to be sure the end condition is achievable. Thanks for pointing that out :)